# How can I use a SSI to create a persistent NavBar across fresh HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ssi

I have my NavBar setup on my main template. I am now going to create my first HTML page that I have setup as a link on my NavBar. It is going to be a completely fresh HTML page with nothing on it besides the inherited styling options. All I want is for this new page to include the NavBar I have already tailored to my needs. What is the quickest and easiest way to do this, so that I can quickly do it on future new HTML pages as well? I am not familiar with PHP currently, so if the answer involves that please try to elaborate a little on the explanation.

I've trued using a basic include on a blank page but it didn't work. So far the only code I've listed below is solely for the setup of my NavBar... Am I supposed to transform the below code into a PHP file in order to do so?

I should include that I am currently hosting using GoDaddy.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
$('#myTopnav a').on('click', function(){
  $('#myTopnav a').toggleClass(' responsive');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 60px 5px 60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition : 0.3s;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #4286f4;
}

.active, .active:focus {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #4286f4;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a:active, .topnav a:visited {
  outline: 0 !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  .topnav{
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: height 2s;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: static;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Begin HTML-->
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Begin head-->
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#"><img src="Images/PlaceholderLogo.png"width="30" height="30"></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#shop">Shop</a>
  <a href="news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```